# Do I need to cite ChatGPT in published writing?

Tags: citations, plagiarism

If I use ChatGPT to generate the initial prose for, say, a 2 paragraph introduction (where I modify and rephrase a little) do I need to cite it or somehow give credit?

This article implies "no"
[World's largest academic publisher says ChatGPT can't be credited as an author](https://www.ghacks.net/2023/01/27/chatgpt-cant-be-credited-academic-author/).

Does anyone have specific guidance, perhaps from a publisher?

Comment: By the way:  The ACL calls "modify and rephrase a little" plagiarism. ["Per ACM definition of plagiarism, it includes not only verbatim or near-verbatim copying of the work of others, but also intentionally paraphrasing portions of another’s work."](https://2023.aclweb.org/blog/ACL-2023-policy/)

Comment: As you mentioned, ChatGPT is the *author* of those paragraphs, not you. Thus, *you* can't publish them at all.

Comment: @Dreamer a computer software can't claim authorship. Only humans can. https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/ca9/16-15469/16-15469-2018-04-23.html - The court of appeals in the 9th circuit found that the monkey can't be the author of the selfie. The case settled but the court brief is concise. Though this is not binding in other circuits, it is likely that other courts will find the same. Chat GPT is not the **author** of the text it generates as much as GIMP is not the author of my images. Or Notepad.exe is not the author of my stories.

Comment: Notwithstanding, the only real hurdle is the Chat GPT TOS. Also, it should be rather obvious how if no *living* creature other than humans can claim authorship, no computer software may either.

Comment: @Mindwin:  They court concluded that the Monkey was the author and that it had constitutional standing.  To sue for copyright infringement in the U.S., the Copyright Act requires that the work be registered with the Copyright Office.  Since the Copyright Office refuses to register works created by animals, the monkey did not have statutory standing.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: Would you think it is OK to have another *human* write your introduction, as long as you cited them? Quoting text in support of your paper is quite a different matter than having someone else write a portion of your paper.

Comment: @JRE : what if you use it purely as a spell-checker or grammar checker? You provide the text, and ask ChatGPT to improve upon it. Where is the line drawn?

Comment: @Mindwin it's true that a piece of software cannot claim authorship. But neither can a human if he didn't actually author the text - which is the case here.
The comparison with Gimp or Notepad is misleading in this regard, because one must tell Gimp and Notepad exactly the steps it should perform - and coming up with these steps is considered the creative work that justifies authorship. With ChatGPT one only states the characteristics of the result and ChatGPT performs the creative step itself.
That being said, a human being may still claim *copyright* on ChatGPT's work, but not authorship.

Comment: Is the author technically the entirety of humanity whose collective works form the basis of the ChatGPT algorithm's data source?

Comment: @Dreamer why would the comparison between two software pieces be misleading if the only difference between them is algorithm complexity and the amount of random noise being introduced on the input? What about Adobe Photoshop? It is the same. A person used a piece of software, and the piece of software generated an output based on the input.

Regarding AI, if you set the temperature and P-values and the random seed, the output is deterministic. You get the same result every single time. Ergo, they are the same.

Comment: from me, the OP - I was not asking about having ChatGPT write part of an academic paper, just about citing its use. But here's a reasonable example - often for the sake of a study or an article, we divide groups of people that were in the study  and give those groups unique names, sometimes memorable group names or archetypes. If I use ChatGPT to suggest a series of clever archetypes - and use them ... well, do I credit ChatGPT?  (and consider this ... if ChaptGPT did not exist - I would probably use WordHippo - which I would not cite).

Comment: @Mindwin authorship is it's not about how complex your tools are - it is about how complex the *remaining* work for the human is. If your only contribution to the resulting work is selecting some numbers that are random even to you then you're not an author of a piece of work. Similarly, if your only contribution to finding an answer is phrasing the question then you're not the author of that answer.

Comment: @CJCornell in that case you may want to (1) clarify your question to make in unambiguously about ChatGPT generating *auxiliary* material and (2) optionally ask a separate question about ChatGPT writing parts of the paper.
Or better yet, make *this* question about ChatGPT writing parts of the paper (since that's what most of the answers seem to be about) and separately ask your actual question about ChatGPT generating auxiliary material.

Comment: *"authorship is it's not about how complex your tools are - it is about how complex the remaining work for the human is"* [citation needed]. Right now, writing prompts for AI is becoming almost a science in itself. Keyword selection, weighing, etc. You are making less of all this work by reducing it to George Jetson's one-button workbench. From WP: *"George's job primarily requires him to repeatedly push a single button"* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Jetson - Beware the strawman.

Answer (score 29):

It looks like you can't use it at all, to be honest.

From the [OpenAI Terms of Use](https://openai.com/terms/)

> You may not: ... (v) represent that output from the Services was human-generated when it is not;...

Given that Springer (from the link in your question) says you can't credit ChatGPT as an author and OpenAI says you have to be up front that the text was generated by ChatGPT, I'd say you're going to have a hard time getting both requirements together.

The [link to the ACL that Franck Dernoncourt posted](https://2023.aclweb.org/blog/ACL-2023-policy/) puts a lot of requirements on the use of ChatGPT for an ACL conference.  Basically, the ACL page says "Don't use it.  If you must use it, consider all these requirements and how you will make sure they are met before you try to convince us that your use of ChatGPT is merited."

The ACL site mentions some cases where it is OK to use text tools - but it does not put ChatGPT in that category.  It also mentions all the ethical and legal doubts surrounding the use of ChatGPT.

---

Why bother with ChatGPT?  You'll have to go through any number of iterations before it tosses out something you like, edit its output, clean it up, and check it for plagiarism (there's always the chance that it'll reconstitute some exact piece of text from the stuff it analyzed.)

Using ChatGPT will simply be more work for a questionable gain.  Write your text yourself.  Then you can be sure that the text says what you meant and that it won't accidentally plagiarise someone else's text.

Comment: Is this legally binding?

Comment: Those are the terms of use you must agree to in order to use ChatGPT.  Whether terms of use are legally binding or not will depend on the legal system of your country.  Do you want to argue it in front a court of law?

Comment: Surely if our OP decided to cite ChatGPT the terms of use would be met since there was no misrepresentation involved?

Comment: @JackAidley:  Right, but then the publication says you can't cite ChatGPT, so you can't put the cite in your paper.  [Catch 22.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch-22)

Comment: Springer is not all publications but, in any case, their guidance ( https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-00191-1 ) says it cannot be _credited as an author_ not that is cannot be cited and, in fact, says that it should be listed in the methods if used

Comment: IANAL but I would say that you could credit it the same way you might credit Google Translate

Comment: -1 incorrect, per Jack's comment.

Comment: “Using ChatGPT will simply be more work for a questionable gain.  Write your text yourself.” There’s a long history of writers using artificial chance-based methods for stimulus — dice-rolling, paper-shuffling, opening dictionaries at random…  I’ve used such techniques for creative writing, and I might well use them in academic writing if I found myself short on inspiration for an exposition.  Similarly, I can easily imagine some people would find ChatGPT helpful in that kind of way.  Not for a finished product, but for lots of initial grit that you can then build pearls around.

Comment: Re "*It looks like you can't use it at all*", The terms you quoted just makes it so you can't use it *without attribution*. If you document its contribution, you are not representing the output as being written by a human.

Answer (score 19):

The article you linked to is rather misleading, in fact [the guidelines](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-00191-1) direct from *Nature* say this:

> First, no LLM tool will be accepted as a credited author on a research paper. That is because any attribution of authorship carries with it accountability for the work, and AI tools cannot take such responsibility.

> Second, researchers using LLM tools should document this use in the methods or acknowledgements sections. If a paper does not include these sections, the introduction or another appropriate section can be used to document the use of the LLM.

Therefore if used they should be cited as per the second piece of guidance here if published in any of Springer's journals. Other journals may have different guidelines.

---

Note: I am deliberately not commenting here on whether I think such use is appropriate or useful, since that is a different question from the one asked here.

Answer (score 9):

Academically... No. You cite the work of people, you can't plagiarise an algorithm. You wouldn't cite a piece of software that did a linear regression for you. ChatGPT is essentially the same, just with a few orders of magnitude more stats going on.

From a [ChatGPT License](https://openai.com/terms/) perspective, you're not allowed to represent its output as human made. However, whether or not you think this license clause is enforceable is a judgement call for you to make.

---

There is a slight complication in that ChatGPT has been trained on millions of lines of other people's work. It may, at times, regurgitate someone else's work verbatim, at which point you have accidentally plagiarised that original work. Further to this, there are cases going through the courts at the moment that argue that these models, and any output from them, de-facto breach the copyright of any unlicensed training material.

Comment: Given how essentially impossible it's going to be to prove that a given section of text was written by ChatGPT to a standard that a court would accept, I'm going to stand behind what I said, it's basically unenforceable

Comment: Well... You can ignore the license if you want to. Software licenses are ignored all the time. You've just got to decide whether the risks associated with doing so are worth it to you. There's no academic consequence to ignoring a software license

Comment: Breaching a license is a civil, not a criminal matter, but I do take your point so I will rephrase it

Comment: You absolutely should cite a piece of software that did a linear regression for you.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to say that ignoring a license *was* ignoring criminal law, just demonstrating the slippery slope of "you can ignore if you want to". The revised wording is better, thanks.

Comment: Are you seriously telling me excel is cited all over the place for doing linear regressions? Please... At that point you might argue you have to cite PgfPlots for drawing your graphs, or LaTex for typesetting the document... Even Linux for providing the OS on which you performed the data analysis. If it's a particularly novel algorithm crucial to some of the results, then sure, but I don't think this meets that

Comment: @ScottishTapWater "A standard that a court would accept" is often "an expert said so, and the adverse party didn't adequately refute it." That's not an impossible standard to meet at all. And that's ignoring the fact that ChatGPT keeps logs of the text it outputs and can definitively prove plagiarism if they are involved or subpoenaed in a hypothetical case.

Comment: @Chris - Even then, it doesn't really matter... AI generated content cannot be copyrighted. So all they could do is say you breached their license... So what? They haven't suffered any damages, so a court won't do anything. The absolute worst that could happen is they close your account

Comment: @ScottishTapWater The original copyright belongs to the authors used in the training corpus. OpenGPT will occasionally cite a piece of text verbatim. Its output is essentially a tied-together, formatted collection of what other people have said on the subject that you ask it.

Comment: @ZOMVID-21 - Ehh... That's an open question that's not yet been settled in court. I find it hard to believe that the courts are going to rule that every person who's in the training set has a collective copyright over the outputs. That's like saying the writer of every book you've ever read should have a copyright in what you write because you're inspired by their work and influenced by it. It's also far more complicated than just tying it together and formatting it... But I do take your point

Comment: @ScottishTapWater I suppose so. But there are cases of verbatim copying. A 100% hit. It's easy to provoke ChatGPT to do that. And that copyright is the author's. As for regenerated content, I guess the courts will have to rule. In software, Cleanroom Reverse Engineering was required to stay clear of the law.

Comment: Sure, if it happens to spit something out verbatim, then you're right. Although I'd imagine the liability would probably lie with the ChatGPT devs, not the person using ChatGPT

Answer (score 4):

> do I need to cite or somehow give credit?

No, except if your [jurisdiction](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/87218/31) or your publisher requires it.

From [OpenAI FAQ](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6783457-chatgpt-faq): "Subject to the [Content Policy](https://labs.openai.com/policies/content-policy) and [Terms](https://openai.com/api/policies/terms/), you own the output you create with ChatGPT, including the right to reprint, sell, and merchandise – regardless of whether output was generated through a free or paid plan."

> if anyone has specific guidance - perhaps from a publisher?

E.g. see the ACL 2023 policy: https://2023.aclweb.org/blog/ACL-2023-policy/.

Note that ChatGPT may plagiarize content.

Answer (score 3):

I am and have been on editorial boards of scientific publications (journals and books). The policy there is quite clear: Texts produced with the help of AI bots are unfit for publication. If not mentioned and found out, authors have plagiarized and will be blacklisted.

Answer (score 3):

Citations, [according to the UNC-Chapel Hill University Libraries](https://guides.lib.unc.edu/citing-information/why-we-cite), serve three major roles in scholarly work: showing how an argument is built on other ideas; indicating which ideas were taken from others and giving due credit; and allowing the reader to track references.

What you would need to do to allow these objectives with LLM output is cite the authors of the text corpus that the LLM was trained on, from which it is (in an mechanistic and non-comprehending fashion) taking ideas. As others have noted, you don't cite an algorithm (though one should specify what algorithm and implementation was used in a research paper); but an LLM isn't merely an algorithm, it's tons and tons and tons of training data.

If you borrow an idea from something I post to the web, as long as you cite me, all's well and good. But when an LLM is trained on something I post, then blends and digests and composts it and spits it out for you, it doesn't tell you that it came from me.

The fact that you cannot trace the idea back and cites its source makes such tools unsuitable for writing anything intended to be intellectually rigorous.

Answer (score 2):

Always, as a rule of thumb, **cite your source** if it didn't come from you, period. (Purdue University, Purdue Online Writing Lab, College of Liberal Arts.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does the AI actually give you the necessary information to identify and cite the sources?  If not, this answer implies it can't be used where citation is required.

Answer (score 1):

What can you cite? The question posed? The answer varies (by intention) when you repeat the same question. The result reads like human text, but in fact isn‘t.

GPT is a language model, not a knowledge model. It has zero clue about what’s factually right or wrong. That‘s why results often sound reasonable for a layman in its field, but hair-raising for the expert, or non-compilable in the case of code created. I.e. GPT tries outputting, even as a kind of hallucination (invented content).

So what can you cite?

Jurisdiction will change here, certainly. So far, personal rights are for persons, not machines.

It may be a choice to put a footnote, stating "these paragraphs were created by ChatGPT 3.5 from the question …". However, it‘s almost always a good idea to just copy the result. E.g. readers will notice the variation in style, the way things are said and expressed.

So I suggest to use such results as an inspiration to formulate your own thoughts the way you do. Then the citation problem disappears and your text will be more coherent.

Comment: Thanks @F1Krazy to correct my own mistakes and those of my input device ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I found this article: [Do you need to cite chat gbt?](https://www.brilliancenw.com/blog/do-you-need-to-cite-chatgbt-if-you-use-it).

It basically outlines that you if you use ChatGBT, you should be citing it to give transparency and credibility to your work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert academically speaking. I'm still currently a student.
From my point of view, and after reading all the comments, I say yes you can.

Actually I'm going to check with my advisor regarding this tomorrow.
Why can't we?

The purpose of AI is online source gathering, what I'm doing is I'm asking ChatGPT to sort citations and references. Also, I recommend to be specific in your question (you have the ownership of the question, it's your logical thinking process. I consider it as an interview for example.)

At the end it's where and why you are using this info for your analysis, reference check, and credibility.

It there wasn't a way to credit ChatGPT (as a search engine) well it should be. AI is out there to make our lives easier, and improve our performance. At the end you need to do the work, in the execution phase.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).